# log4j2 AsyncAppender occured a memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, log4j2, java.util.concurrent

log4j2 version : 2.7
My project is a high concurrent system, I use log4j2 asyncAppender to save logs, but every nigh at 00:00:00 when the rollover strategy triggering, the event blocked at rollover process.
the appender create lots of threads and occured a memory leak, here is my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="info">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="logDir">/data/logs/q-mix</Property>
        <Property name="rollingSuffix">log.gz</Property>
        <Property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN">%clr{%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}{faint} %clr{%5p} %clr{%5.5T}{magenta} %clr{---}{faint} %clr{[%20.20t]}{faint} %clr{%-40.40c{1.}}{cyan} %clr{:}{faint} %m%n</Property>
        <Property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p %5.5T --- [%20.20t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>


    <appenders>
        <console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}" />
        </console>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFileInfo" fileName="${logDir}/info.log"
                     filePattern="${logDir}/logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i-info.${rollingSuffix}">
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="INFO"/>
            </Filters>
            <PatternLayout pattern="${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="2048 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="80">
                <Delete basePath="${logDir}/logs/" maxDepth="1">
                    <IfFileName glob="*.${rollingSuffix}">
                        <IfAny>
                            <IfAccumulatedFileSize exceeds="50 GB" />
                            <IfLastModified age="15d" />
                        </IfAny>
                    </IfFileName>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFileWarn" fileName="${logDir}/warn.log"
                     filePattern="${logDir}/logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i-warn.${rollingSuffix}">
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="WARN"/>
            </Filters>
            <PatternLayout pattern="${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1024 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="40"/>
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFileError" fileName="${logDir}/error.log"
                     filePattern="${logDir}/logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i-error.${rollingSuffix}">
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1024 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="40"/>
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFileAlarm" fileName="${logDir}/alarm.log"
                     filePattern="${logDir}/logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i-alarm.${rollingSuffix}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1024 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="40"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <Async name="async" bufferSize="1024000">
            <!--            <appender-ref ref="Console"/>-->
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileInfo"/>
            <!--            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileWarn"/>-->
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileError"/>
        </Async>
    </appenders>

    <loggers>
        <logger name="com.upex.exchange.robot.util.AlarmUtils" level="error">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAlarm"/>
        </logger>
        <root level="info">
            <appender-ref ref="async"/>
        </root>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

**Here is the stacktrace:**

```
AsyncAppender-async
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(ZJ)V (Native Method)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Ljava/lang/Object;)V (LockSupport.java:175)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt()Z (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(I)V (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(I)V (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
  at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire()V (Semaphore.java:312)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.rollover(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/RolloverStrategy;)Z (RollingFileManager.java:247)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.rollover()V (RollingFileManager.java:192)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.checkRollover(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/LogEvent;)V (RollingFileManager.java:175)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.append(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/LogEvent;)V (RollingFileAppender.java:280)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/LogEvent;)V (AppenderControl.java:156)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/LogEvent;)V (AppenderControl.java:129)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/LogEvent;)V (AppenderControl.java:120)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/LogEvent;)V (AppenderControl.java:84)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender$AsyncThread.callAppenders(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/LogEvent;)Z (AsyncAppender.java:451)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender$AsyncThread.run()V (AsyncAppender.java:404)
```

**This is the Eclipse Memory Analyzer leak report:**

```
One instance of "java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue" loaded by "<system class loader>" occupies 897,341,688 (95.23%) bytes. 
The instance is referenced by org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender$AsyncThread @ 0xc0700150 AsyncAppender-async , 
loaded by "org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0xc0400000". 
The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.lang.Object[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".

The stacktrace of this Thread is available. See stacktrace.



Keywords
java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue
java.lang.Object[]
org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0xc0400000
```

**How can i change some configs to resolve this problem, I realy need some help. Thanks a lot.**

Sorry for my english grammar

Answer (score 0):

According to log4j's sugguest I upgrade the log4j2 to version 2.14

**LMAX Disruptor technology. Asynchronous Loggers internally use the Disruptor, a lock-free inter-thread communication library, instead of queues, resulting in higher throughput and lower latency.**

the new config xml like this:

```
    <appenders>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingFileWarn" fileName="${logDir}/warn.log"
                                 filePattern="${logDir}/logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i-warn.${rollingSuffix}" immediateFlush="false">
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="WARN"/>
            </Filters>
            <PatternLayout pattern="${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1024 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="40"/>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </appenders>

    <loggers>
        <logger name="com.upex.exchange.robot.util.AlarmUtils" level="error">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAlarm"/>
        </logger>
        <AsyncRoot level="info" includeLocation="true">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileInfo"/>
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileError"/>
        </AsyncRoot>
    </loggers>
```

Add a log4j2.component.properties to classpath,content config:

```
log4j2.AsyncQueueFullPolicy=Discard
AsyncLoggerConfig.SynchronizeEnqueueWhenQueueFull=true
AsyncLoggerConfig.RingBufferSize=131072
```

This new way may solve the memory leak problem(not confirmed), Because when the TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy started, the cpu load increased five times than usual , it seams still blocked when policy is triggering. However, this configuration limits the queue length and queue full policy. I will continue to observe